# Companion Visa for family

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, brussels

We (myself and kids) recently got belgian nationality. A friend of mine mentioned that my wife can accompany me and kids to UK for short trips with her exisiting Indian passport.
I tried looking online but no information about it. Can someone help?

Thanks
Manish

Comment: You can check visa requirements here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa If your wife doesn’t have an Article 10 residence card, she can apply for an EEA Family Permit to enter the UK https://www.gov.uk/family-permit

Comment: @Traveller's comments are true until 29th March 2019 when Britain leaves the EU, after which it's currently unclear what arrangements will prevail

Answer (score 1):

You can check visa requirements here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa If your wife doesn’t have an Article 10 residence card, she can apply free of charge for an EEA Family Permit to enter the UK  https://www.gov.uk/family-permit
After 29th March 2019, when the UK leaves the EU, it’s currently unclear what arrangements will prevail.